# What is the proper way to normalize negative values?

Tags: c#, image-processing, convolution

Suppose, i have performed a convolution operation with the following Kernel:

```
double[,] image = ImageDataConverter.ToDouble2d(lena);
double[,] kernel = new double[,] { { 2, 0, 0, }, 
                                   { 0,-1, 0, }, 
                                   { 0, 0,-1, }, };  
double[,] conv = Convolution.LinearConvolutionInSpatialDomain(image, kernel );
```

It is understandable that a convolution with this kernel will give rise to some negative values in the 2d double array.

Obviously, the following method:

```
    public static void Rescale(double[,] convolve)
    {
        int imageWidth = convolve.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = convolve.GetLength(1);

        double maxAmp = 0.0;

        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
            {
                maxAmp = Math.Max(maxAmp, convolve[i, j]);
            }
        }

        double scale = 1 / maxAmp;

        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
            {
                double d = convolve[i, j] * scale;
                convolve[i, j] = d;
            }
        }
    }
```

won't be able to re-scale those values between 0-1.

So, what is the standard procedure to achieve the normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following function to solve my issue:

```
    private static double Constraint(double value, double minRange, double maxRange, 
                                           double minVal, double maxVal)
    {
        return (((value - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)) * 
                  (maxRange - minRange) + minRange);
    }
```

This function is written on the basis of **[this link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/33445/15743)**.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the minimum as well as the maximum. Change the scale to `double scale = 1 / (Math.abs(minAmp) + maxAmp)` and add the `minAmp` before applying the scale.

`double d = (convolve[i, j] + Math.abs(minAmp)) * scale`

Comment: Basically, you are shifting your data first with the minimum value to get all positive values. Then you are applying the same operation on the positive values.

Answer (score -1):

I used the minmax scaler from the preprocessing package to normalize values between 0 and 1 for all values (most of them were negative)

Comment: You should try giving an example